# Text file with row headings to excel file with columns

Tags: import, textfiles

A text file with the following content:

```
userId=10101
givenname=Mark
orclmaidenname=Visser
mail=m.visser@somecompany.nl

userID=10102
givenname=Jan
orclmaidenname=Klaassen

userID=10104
givenname=Jessica
orclmaidenname=Host
mail=j.host@somecompany.nl
```

And so on.

How do I convert this txt file to an excel worksheet where the row headings from the text file will be column headers and the rows from the excel sheet are filled with the corresponding values from the text file?

The txt file has more than 1000 items, but not all items have the same row headings (for example some do not have a "mail").

Hope someone has a clear insight...

Comment: This would be quite the macro, but we're not a script writing service. Your solution macro needs a few main steps: import the data, get the unique "titles" get the values for each title, assemble the table. This isn't particularly complicated really. But, please try a little bit of this yourself and then show us what you've done, and we can help keep you going in the right direction, or steer you straight when you've gone wrong.